# Wildcards in ignored tags are not working

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, ignored-tags

I was looking for a way to specify wildcards in tags in my ignored list, since there are so many version tags of php frameworks that I have little to no experience in. It got annoying to add them all.

I found quite a few questions on meta about variations of this request and finally a link to this blog post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/07/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/

This is exactly what I'm looking for, except it deosn't seem to work.

Here is the question list with a wildcard specified:
[image]
All the questions should be greyed out.

In this case, since all these questions are tagged with the base `magento` tag, they are all greyed out when adding that specific tag:
[image]

What am I doing wrong with my wildcard tag?

Comment: That should work, according to [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do).

Comment: slightly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363139/advanced-search-options-intags-mine-does-not-support-tagwildcards

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce this anymore, so it looks like the issue got fixed at some point.