# There seems to be a problem with wildcards in watched/ignored tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, ignored-tags, wildcard

*First off, be careful if you try to experiment with this. Somehow I inadvertently removed all my wildcard tags from watched tags and I can't put them back.*

---

I was trying to add a tag with a wildcard to my ignored tags, and it wasn't working.

I saw this question: [Wildcards in ignored tags are not working](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346540/wildcards-in-ignored-tags-are-not-working), and based on the screenshots there it looks like you used to be able to at least add an asterisk to a tag name in ignored tags, even if it didn't actually do anything.

I was trying to do the same thing they're asking about there, but now instead of an ignored tag with a wildcard not working as expected, I can't even add the asterisk to the tag name. It gets removed as soon as I tab/enter/click the "Add" button. It's the same in the main page sidebar and in my profile "Tag watching and Ignoring" section, but [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do) seems to indicate that it should work.

I assumed that the fact that the asterisk is actively removed now means that no wildcards in ignored tags is by design, but just wanted to verify that is the case and I wasn't just doing it wrong, so I asked this question.

Then out of curiosity I tried to add a tag with an asterisk to my watched tags, and it did the same things. A second later, I noticed that all the tags I previously had in watched tags with wildcards were not there any more.

Comment: I have asterisks in my ignored tags. But yeah, they don't seem to actually be applied as wildcards.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Were you able to add them like that just now, or did you already have them entered that way? Just curious. I think if they don't work, it makes sense to not let them be added. But we should probably adjust that FAQ if that's the case.

Comment: I had pre-existing tags with asterisks (which have mysteriously removed their asterisks while I was writing this). I just now tried adding `*test*`, and the first time it was immediately changed to `testing`. Thinking I had selected that entry by mistake, I tried again and it was added as `*test*` as expected, but as soon as focus left the edit area, it changed to `testing`. Funny that wildcards can be typed to display a drop-down of matching tags, but actually adding a wildcard doesn't work. `testing` isn't even the first entry in the drop-down, `unit-testing` is (`testing` is second).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for elaborating, good to know I'm not alone. :-) I wonder if I should re-tag this as a bug. Every other post I can find about it just says something like "yes, you can do this, it works"

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed it does the same thing in watched tags, and then suddenly all my pre-existing asterisks in watched tags disappeared

Comment: I have many tags with asterisks in my watch list, and the wildcards do work fine. I don't dare edit that list now!

Comment: Contrary to @RemyLebeau’s experience I’ve been ignoring the wildcard tag [facebook*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook*) for ages and it seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: "twitt does not exist on this site", the filter did work, untill I tried adding a new filter, it got removed as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad - I switched the Watch/Ignore code to use a different tag input sanitization method that supported synonyms and *claimed* that it supported wildcards, but in fact did not. :)

That's fixed now, so you should be able to use wildcards in watched and ignored tags.

Comment: @pnuts Elaborate? What am I looking at/how does that URL come up on the site?

Comment: @pnuts Huh, weird. `[document*]` works just fine on SO. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯